# quote query fails in eTrade api

Tags: etrade-api

I am getting protocol error on following url for quote query. What is wrong here in the url?

> ***/market/rest/quote/GOOG:2012:2:18:CALL:400?detailFlag=OPTIONS

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Resolved. You have to sign "Real Time Quote Agreement on the website" otherwise eTrade wont allow you to pull the data.